# how to use linq in struct

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, struct, lambda

When i use LINQ in my struct in the silverlight project, this error comes. please help out why?

> Anonymous methods, lambda expressions, and query expressions inside
>   structs cannot access instance members of 'this'. Consider copying
>   'this' to a local variable outside the anonymous method, lambda
>   expression or query expression and using the local instead.

Comment: Please provide code where this error is coming.

Comment: isn't this too easy to find on google?

Comment: In most standard cases, if you are using a `struct`, you are probably *doing it wrong*. `struct` is pretty rare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same problem while trying to use LINQ in struct. struct is value type so it LINQ cannot be used in it. Instead of this, make a separate class, create functions there with LINQ based stuff of yours, and access those functions using the object of that class.